# SPARQL query doesn't provide good results

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, fuseki

I want to extract the person name, tweet id and date from an RDF file about migration of humans, but the results provided by the SPARQL query are combined which is wrong. The expected result should have just 2 rows of data. Here is the RDF data:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:migration="http://xmlns.com/migration#" xmlns:location="http://xmlns.com/location#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/migration#">
    <migration:to rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <location:longitude>11.559682</location:longitude>
        <location:latitude>48.135582</location:latitude>
        <location:country>Germany</location:country>
        <location:city>Munich</location:city>
    </migration:to>
    <migration:from rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <location:longitude>27.5903865</location:longitude>
        <location:latitude>47.1560806</location:latitude>
        <location:country>Romania</location:country>
        <location:city>Iasi</location:city>
    </migration:from>
    <migration:date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">Fri Dec 16 15:28:52 EET 2016</migration:date>
    <migration:person rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">vrachieru_</migration:person>
    <migration:tweetId rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1</migration:tweetId>
</rdf:Description>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/migration#">
    <migration:to rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <location:longitude>12</location:longitude>
        <location:latitude>12</location:latitude>
        <location:country>Singapore</location:country>
        <location:city>Singapore</location:city>
    </migration:to>
    <migration:from rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <location:longitude>13</location:longitude>
        <location:latitude>13</location:latitude>
        <location:country>Romania</location:country>
        <location:city>Bucharest</location:city>
    </migration:from>
    <migration:date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">Tue Dec 16 15:28:52 EET 2016</migration:date>
    <migration:person rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ioana</migration:person>
    <migration:tweetId rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">2</migration:tweetId>
</rdf:Description>
```

and here is the SPARQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT  ?date ?person_name ?tweet_id
WHERE {
  ?migration <http://xmlns.com/migration#date> ?date.
  ?migration <http://xmlns.com/migration#person> ?person_name.
  ?migration <http://xmlns.com/migration#tweetId> ?tweet_id
}
LIMIT 25
```

and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf5rr.png)  are the results, all mixed which is not what I expected.
I appreciate some help on how to do a good SPARQL query to extract just the data I want about each migration.

Comment: if you have 3 columns with 2 values per column, the obvious output of the cartesian product is `2^3=8` rows.

Comment: If you also select the `?migration`, you'll get two rows as result I guess. Because then, the other values are bound to the migration.

Comment: By the way, the RDF/XML data is wrong resp. missing something since you have two resources with the same URI `http://xmlns.com/migration#` and seomthing behind the `#` is missing, e.g. `http://xmlns.com/migration#1` and `http://xmlns.com/migration#2`

Comment: Thank you very very much! You are absolutely right! I must identify each migration using an unique id as you said, and the results will be as expected.